# How to link a .a file in C++

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to get the [yaml-cpp parser](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) working on my computer. I followed the instructions on the README, which generated the file `libyaml-cpp.a` with no errors or warnings. Then I copied that file into a directory, let's call it `/path/to/files`, where I also put `b.yaml`, and `main.cpp`, which contains the following text:

```
// main.cpp

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("b.yaml");
  return 0;
}
```

This comes from the first line of the [yaml-cpp tutorial](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial). I tried compiling this while linking to the `yaml-cpp` library in a few different ways, all of which lead to the same compile-time error: `use of undeclared identifier 'YAML'`. Here are some of the things I tried:

1. `g++ main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -L/path/to/files`
2. `g++ main.cpp libyaml-cpp.a`
3. `g++ main.cpp libyaml-cpp.a -lyaml-cpp -L/path/to/files`

and so on. How do I compile this correctly or more properly debug  this process?

==EDIT==

Now my `main.cpp` file looks like this:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "yaml.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("b.yaml");
  return 0;
}
```

Here's my compile command and error message:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -I/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/include -L/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/build
main.cpp:10:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'YAML'
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("b.yaml");
  ^
main.cpp:10:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'YAML'
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("b.yaml");
                      ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

`/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/include` contains a `yaml-cpp` directory, which in turn contains all the `.h` files including `yaml.h`. `/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/build` contains the `lyaml-cpp.a` file.

Comment: Have you included the `yaml.h` in your `main.cpp` and corresponding `-I` flag with path to `yaml.h` in compilation

Comment: @dlmeetei Nope, trying that now...having some path issues

Comment: You aren't having a link issue. You are having a compilation issue. You should post the whole error verbatim, as it may have some information which you have not realized is relevant, but is relevant.

Comment: Your compile line will look something like this `g++ main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -L/path/to/files -I/path/to/include`

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks for the input! I just added more updated and more detailed info showing the error I'm seeing.

Comment: is it resolved now?

Comment: @dlmeetei nope, I'll get back to it in a few hours but the edit above is still current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded `yaml-cpp` and tried out, Here is a working version

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h" //You need to prepend the yaml-cpp

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
     YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("b.yaml");
     //return 0; In cpp, return 0 is not required on main, hence commented
}
```

The compile using `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -I/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/include -L/Users/benlindsay/scratch/yaml-cpp/build`

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm

Comment: @BenLindsay, Happy that I could be of help :)